# configure [go build]/[go test] etc to show absolute paths in diagnostic messages

Tags: go

Is there a way to configure/direct `go build`, `go test` etc to report file locations using absolute paths? I frequently run `go build` from my editor (which parses the output) and it would be convenient if the current working directory of the `go build` process and the editor itself did not need to match.

So far, the only solution I've found is to wrap `go build` in a script that determines absolute paths to files, then immediately `cd`s to a temporary directory before invoking `go build` with the `realpath`'d original arguments.

Creating a temporary directory and `cd`'ing to it just to trick the go tools seems like a bizarre workaround, so I'm wondering if there's a more direct solution.

*Is there a way to configure the `go tools` to report absolute paths besides wrapping them and `cd`ing to random directories?*

Suppose that my `GOPATH` is `/go` and that I have the following file.

```
// /go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26/main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hi")
}
```

Suppose I intentionally introduce an error in this file.

```
// /go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26/main.go
package main

// import (
//  "fmt"
// )

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hi")
}
```

`go build main.go` reports the following error:

```
/go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26$ go build main.go
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:9: undefined: fmt in fmt.Println
   2
```

`go build ...` still reports `./main.go` as the path to the file if given an absolute path

```
/go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26$ go build `realpath main.go`
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:9: undefined: fmt in fmt.Println
   2
```

`go build` seems to produce paths relative to the directory it was invoked from:

These are the paths that `go build` produces when directed to `cd` to the root directory first.

```
/go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26$ (a=`realpath main.go` && cd / && go build $a)
# command-line-arguments
go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26/main.go:9: undefined: fmt in fmt.Println
   2
```

It's possible to coax `go build` into emitting absolute paths by `cd`-ing to a directory that's guaranteed to be fresh

```
/go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26$ (a=`realpath main.go` && cd `mktemp -d` && go build $a)
# command-line-arguments
/go/src/nonexistent-website.com/example-2019-10-26/main.go:9: undefined: fmt in fmt.Println
   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure the go tools to report absolute paths besides wrapping them and cding to random directories?

No.